# How to programmatically communicate with Apache?

Tags: python, web-applications, port, reverse-proxy, shared-hosting

So many web applications these days run on their own microservers, it can be hard to implement them on shared hosting platforms. The apps listen on a dedicated port you can customize or reverse proxy, but shared hosting usually only has 80 and 443 open.

Just as an example, the handy web-based editor [ICEcoder](https://icecoder.net/) is a PHP application, so you just drop the files in a directory and away you go. However, the [Cloud9](https://github.com/c9/core) editor runs its own server. You can customize the port, but again, you cant run the reverse proxy.

I had the idea of using a PHP or Python CGI script as an intermediary. Something like:

*www.mydomain/mydirectory/middleman.py*

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import urlparse, json
# hpyothetical apache api
import apache

parsed_path = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)

response = apache(url=parsed_path, port=8080)

sendStuffBack(response)
```

Would this be possible with Apache? How would I implement it?

**Edit:**
Here is what I did based on @grawity's answer.

*helloflask.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

*middle.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

import requests
#response = requests.get("http://localhost:5000")
response = requests.get("http://localhost:8888/token=8a387fe88d662e2568f9b8ec2398191452492e7184536670")

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Can you edit your Question to include a question?

Comment: @Spiff Is this better? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python project **is** a reverse proxy, and the API you're looking for is just ordinary HTTP. (After all, that's how web browsers interact with Apache already...)

To make HTTP requests, you need a client like `urllib` or `requests`:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://" + apache_host + ":8080/" + parsed_path)
```

By default, all your apps and microservers will think that all clients come from localhost. If that's a problem, see if your apps accept the [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) header. (If they do, include it in all your requests.)

Comment: It should. Port 8080 is being accessed by your Python script – not by the user themself. (In any case, how else would you access the "API" anyway?)

Comment: Ok! This did work to an extent. I followed the get with just `print(response.text)`. I started a hello world flask app on port 5000, and I got the "hello world." However, when I made a get request to a jupyter notebook running on port 8888, I get the page malformed. I compared the source to what I get from a direct call, and the source is identical. So I may need to start a new issue to find out what is not working.

Comment: Quick note -- things like relative links to images (e.g. `<img src = "some-image.jpg">`) will need to be rewritten with the full path not to be broken e.g. `<img src = "http://some-site.com/path/to/some-image.jpg">`).

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Are you sure it's not the opposite? The whole idea of relative links is that they work regardless of path... but absolute links certainly need to be rewritten.

Comment: @grawity Well, I guess I shouldn't speak in absolutes. =) If you have a `<base>` tag, you can just re-write that, obviously. If not (assuming I am not missing something else very easy), you could insert one, I suppose. The other option to avoid rewriting would be to recreate the exact same folder structure (same folder names/same image locations) in your web directory, starting from the root, but that seems messy.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, relative URLs are interpreted from the base URL in the browser. So when a browser goes to fetch `<img src = "some-image.jpg">`, if the script lives at "www.somesite.com", the request for the image made by the browser from the returned html is "www.somesite.com/some-image.jpg"... even if the HTML came from "internalhost:8080".

Comment: @Anaksunaman, you are exactly correct. It took me a while to figure it out. And I'm not sure what to do to fix it. I decided to clarify my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673359/how-to-properly-return-http-response-from-python-requests-library-want-a-python), but got no responses. In any case, you are completely correct, and I'm not sure how to solve it. Strange these comments did not show up in my notification.

Comment: @abalter Technology, eh? =) I am not sure I could help much overall, but I think a nudge in the right direction could be [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). I have used it for some personal scraping/conversion projects and it can certainly manipulate your final html output, assuming you can figure out how you want that done.