# How to properly return http response from Python Requests library (want a Python reverse proxy)

Tags: python, apache, proxy, python-requests

This question continues from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635552/how-to-programmatically-communicate-with-apache).

I want to create a reverse proxy of sorts that will allow me to host an application that runs on a specified port on a server that does not have that port open. But I do not want take over ports 80/443 because I need to have other apps running on that server. Instead, I want an app running at `localhost:####` to be served from a suburl or subdomain such as `http://myserver/myapp`.

Here is what I tried:

*helloflask.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

*middle.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

import requests
#response = requests.get("http://localhost:5000")
response = requests.get("http://localhost:8888/token=8a387fe88d662e2568f9b8ec2398191452492e7184536670")

print(response.text)
```

When I run `helloflask.py` it runs on port 5000, and I can visit `mydomain/middle.py` and get the correct response of "Hello World!" displayed in the browser.

However, when I run a jupyter notebook on port 8888, I get a malformed web page. Strangely, the page sources are identical ([see the diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/nJceWVS2)).

So, what do I need to do to make jupyter run from the proxy?

Here is an image of how the page appears through `middle.py`. The link to IPythonParallel works, but no other links or controls function in any way.

[image]

Comment: If you need to manipulate the HTML itself, [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) may be useful to you.